# Avoiding sending message with html tags making elements

Tags: javascript, html

If a user makes a message like this

"lol `<button class="w3-button w3-red w3-hover-red" onclick="document.body.innerHTML='';">Do Not Press</button>` who trusts that?"

It would actually create a red button that says 'Do Not Press', but I don't want to do that.
I want it to show just the message, which should say `<button class="w3-button w3-red w3-hover-red" onclick="document.body.innerHTML='';">Do Not Press</button>` instead of a red button.

When a person sends a message, the script creates a div with the message as the innerHTML.

Is there a solution to this? I mean, Facebook has one but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Treat the input as text then, and not as HTML …

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are sanitizing in PHP - then use `htmlspecialchars($input)`

If you are sanitizing in JavaScript - then use a function like this

```
function escapeHTML(str)
{
  return str.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s)
  {
    var entityMap =
    {
      "&": "&amp;",
      "<": "&lt;",
      ">": "&gt;",
      '"': '&quot;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      "/": '&#x2F;'
    };

    return entityMap[s];
  });
}
```

Comment: hmm.. i didn't know functions can be used there.

Comment: Do you accept my answer ?